# Why does this non-coinbase transaction not have a sender address?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, transaction-input

This is the transaction in concern: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/6b1c57d98a557b5f578c02f6c386ef049df5890ebddd01d286bf345f47c5cecc

I think it is a transaction having nothing to do with coinbase because there is a prev_out field in the items in the input array. However, there is no field "addr" in the prev_out item, unlike this transaciton: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/304b90ea66d80652f2473c0b455bfa7775fa32b2de3f170c15bfe8e65c0a7adc 
and most of the other transactions.

Is there any reason for lacking an "addr" field? Could this indicate some malpractice?

Comment: If I search by tx_index of that prev_out entry: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/140787227, there is an entry with the same tx_index and same value, AND having the field "addr".

Answer (score 1):

the transaction 6b1c57d98a557b5f578c02f6c386ef049df5890ebddd01d286bf345f47c5cecc spends **multisignature** output.

blockchain.info does not resolve such kind of inputs to addresses

Comment: Will I be able to get the correct address by blockchain.info/rawtx/140787227 for this transaction?

Comment: There are three "addresses" https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/6b1c57d98a557b5f578c02f6c386ef049df5890ebddd01d286bf345f47c5cecc

Comment: What do you mean by "addresses" (with quotation marks)?

Comment: what do YOU mean by addresses without quotation? Not all transactions go from and to addresses.

Comment: You said "There are three 'addresses'." So what is the difference between the addresses involved in the transaction and the addresses involved in the majority of the other transactions? (except for they participated in a multisig output)

Comment: there are no addresses in bitcoin protocol

Comment: Are you saying that there are only wallets in bitcoin protocol? If yes, then I understand what you mean.

Comment: I have another question regarding the same transaction. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51772/what-does-this-output-item-in-the-result-of-the-call-with-blocktrail-api-mean Would you mind if you answer it? (I find a way to get the addresses, but another issue appeared.)

Comment: Apart from multisig transaction, is there any other type of transactions in which some of the relevant addresses which are not recorded in the output of blockchain api?