# Are there other ways to have more than one address involved in a SINGLE transaction input or a SINGLE transaction output?

Tags: transactions, multi-signature, output, transaction-input

Full question:
Except for the case of multisignature, are there other ways to have more than one address involved in a SINGLE transaction input or a SINGLE transaction output?

Comment: what is "address"?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address  How should I refer to it more properly?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin address is human-readable form for representation **output script**. So, one output transfers funds to one address **by the definition** of the term **address**.

One transaction input **always** spends **one** output of the prevoius transaction.

Your question has no sense.

Comment: How is bitcoin address an output script? As it says in the link, bitcoin address "represents a possible destination for a bitcoin payment".

Comment: I understand that "One transaction input always spends one output of the prevoius transaction". However, that does not seem to mean that each output goes to one address. Such as in the transaction referred to in this question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51772/what-does-this-output-item-in-the-result-of-the-call-with-blocktrail-api-mean   There is an output with three addresses involved as multisig.  I am asking if there are other cases in which input/output involves multiple addresses.

Comment: the multisig address is **one** address/destination created from several public keys. the block-explorers and wallets usually/sometimes decode it to several p2pkh addresses for readability

Comment: Then why does the multisig addresses have entries like that: "multisig_addresses":["1HhfcdD1hRaim17m5qLEwGgHY7PBTb1Dof","1FkQMTyqzD2BK5PsmWX13AeJAHz5NEw7gq","17VLRV4y7g15KNhCepYvgigHHvREzbEmRn"]

Comment: @Aqqqq Because Bitcoin Core lists the addresses for all the public keys involved. I think it's a historic mistake that it does that, it's just confusing. From the network's point of view, a multisig output is a single script, and is spent by a single input with a single script - just one that happens to contain signatures by multiple keys.

Comment: @PieterWuille So are there other ways for an transaction input/output to contain contain signatures by multiple keys similar to the case in multi signature?

Comment: I'd say that is the definition of multisig...

Comment: @PieterWuille Sorry, I want to ask that if there are other ways that multiple keys involve in a transaction input/output (similar to the case in multi signature).

Comment: Again, that's the definition of multisig.